# Bash Regex how to retrieve a value

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to extract from the following file contents using regex

```
# # Be sure to run `pod lib lint My Pod.podspec' to ensure this is a # valid spec before submitting. # # Any lines starting with a # are optional, but their use is encouraged # To learn more about a Podspec see http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html # Pod::Spec.new do |s| s.name = "My Pod" s.version = "0.1.0" s.summary = "My Pod Stuff" # This description is used to generate tags and improve search results. # Think: What does it do? Why did you write it? What is the focus? # Try to keep it short, snappy and to the point. # Write the description between the DESC delimiters below. Finally, don't worry about the indent, CocoaPods strips it! s.description = <<-DESC Localize StoryBoard automatically. DESC s.homepage = "https://github.com/pod/MyPod.git" # s.screenshots = "www.example.com/screenshots_1", "www.example.com/screenshots_2" s.license = 'MIT' s.author = { } s.source = { :git => "https://github.com/controllerkit/MyPod.git", :tag => s.version.to_s } # s.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/<TWITTER_USERNAME>' s.platform = :ios, '7.0' s.requires_arc = true s.source_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*' s.resource_bundles = { 'My Pod' => ['Pod/Assets/*.png'] } # s.public_header_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.h' # s.frameworks = 'UIKit', 'MapKit' s.dependency 'CocoaLumberjack', '~> 2' s.dependency 'BlocksKit' end
```

This is the bash that I am using but the echo returns nothing. What am I doing wrong in my bash script? I basically want to extract the s.name value from the file for use in my script later.

```
[[ "$podSpecValues" =~ 's\.name\s+=\s+"(.*?)"' ]] 
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

where $podSpecValues is the string of the file above. Using https://regex101.com/r/yZ3kM7/8 shows that the regex should be correct.

The output from the file above should be My Pod

Thanks
DMCApps

Comment: can you sample of the desired output.

Comment: The output should be the value between the "s after s.name ... i.e. the output from the sample file should be My Pod

Comment: Can you also confirm that your input really is *all on one line*? It looks like it wants to be multiple lines that start with hashes. Oh, and please format your output in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
[[ "$podSpecValues" =~ s\.name\ +=\ +\"([^\"]*)\" ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

This is what I see:

```
$ echo ${BASH_VERSION} 
4.3.11(1)-release
$ podSpecValues='Pod::Spec.new do |s| s.name = "My Pod" s.version = "0.1.0" s.summary = "It does stuff"'
$ [[ "$podSpecValues" =~ s\.name\ +=\ +\"([^\"]*)\" ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" | cat -A
My Pod$
```

Comments on the OP:

- As of Bash 3.2, quoting the RHS pattern leads to literal string matching. I find that *very* counterintuitive.
- The Bash regex flavor will match whitespace `[[:space:]]` not with `\s`. To match a single space character, use `"\ "` (without the double quotes!).
- I'm not sure what the question mark `?` is for inside the `()`.
- Inside the `()`, the `*` must not match double quotes `"`, else you will get characters beyond the closing `"`.

Comment: This doesn't echo anything

Comment: Added what I see. What does `podSpecValues` contain in your case?

Comment: hmm maybe it's my version? I'm running GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)

Comment: @DMCApps: No, the example also works with your Bash version.

Comment: @mklement0 I added the full echo of the file contents

Comment: When I dump that into a file `foo`, this works for me: `[[ "$(cat foo)" =~ s\.name\ *=\ *\"([^\"]*)\" ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"`.

Comment: Added version which matches all whitespace around `=`, not just space chars. Could it be that you have tabs in there, that disappear when pasted into the OP?

Comment: @MateiDavid - while you may have come up with something that works, it always improves an answer if you *explain* what you did, why it works, and why the attempt that the OP made didn't work. Can you add some context to your answer?

Comment: Interesting, when I added the full cat command with the path to my file in the regex it works! ... I think the issue came down to the fact that I was storing the cat into a variable as `podSpecFileContents=$(cat $podSpec)` but I needed to have quotes around the command output and then it worked fine ... i.e. once I changed it to `podSpecFileContents="$(cat $podSpec)"` it worked why did the quotes here make such a big difference when in the `[[ "$podSpecValues" =~ s\.name[[:space:]]+=[[:space:]]+\"([^\"]*)\" ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"` call I was surrounding the variable by quotes?

Comment: @MateiDavid also that regex doesn't seem to work, but the original you posted does `[[ "$podSpecFileContents" =~ s\.name\ *=\ *\"([^\"]*)\" ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"` if you could change it back to that then it's good to go

Comment: That is strange, I would expect `a=$(cmd)` not to do any substitution, so that quoting should be unnecessary. Maybe it's an issue with the `bash` version? Try `a=$(echo '# "1"'); echo "$a"`. With Bash 4, I see `# "1"`.

Comment: I updated to the most recent bash (seeing as I was quite out of date) so I won't be able to try that out for my version. Sorry

Comment: So you new Bash doesn't match white space with `[[:space:]]`? `[[ "$(echo '1 2')" =~ 1[[:space:]]2 ]] && echo yes`?

Comment: that works. I wonder if it's because the original file has tabs between s.name [tab spacing]= "My Pod"?

Comment: Then I'd expect `[[:space:]]` to work but not `"\ "` (without the double quotes! Aside: is there a way to end a code snippet with a space?!). Either way, reverted to original version.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use `sed`?

```
$echo 'Pod::Spec.new do |s| s.name = "My Pod" s.version = "0.1.0" s.summary = "It does stuff"' | sed 's/\(.* s\.name\s*=\s\"\)\([^"]*\)\(.*$\)/\2/g'
$My Pod
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're doing with this? I imagine the OP isn't familiar with sed scripting, so a breakdown of your script and its regex would undoubtedly improve this answer.

Comment: if you suggest, then it is better to attach an example of usage. `sed` does have tons of parameters.